# ignore duplicated string values while concatinating them in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

i managed to concatenate string values in my mongodb collection  into a single result but i couldnt manage to ignore the duplicated strings
this is an example of my attempt :
https://mongoplayground.net/p/T1TmxpGy6nV

Comment: you could use $addToSet to suppress duplicates, then concatenate the array items together into a single string.

Comment: link is broken - this playground doesn't exist error.

Comment: there is a _ at the end of the link  the playground is working fine

Comment: @barrypicker i updated it

Comment: if you want the distinct comments i think you need  [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ml9IduAY6Uw) , if you want the distinct words in comments you have to split the comment.

Comment: thanks the  $addToSet works but now when i insert it into the aggregation that im working on it returns empty fields this is m attempt and i think the poblem is the wa i used the $addToSet mongoplayground.net/p/dB3xBFsIfun

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoplayground example uses $push.  $push does not suppress duplicates, whereas $addToSet does.  Here is an agg you might consider...

(I took liberty to remove null values, and I took liberty to separate results by a comma.  No sort order of values is specified so they are added in an out-of-order condition.)

**Aggregation Example**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "comment": { $ne: null } }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: null,
            comments: { $addToSet: "$comment" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:
        {
            "comments":
            {
                $reduce:
                {
                    input: "$comments",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in:
                    {
                        "$cond":
                        {
                            if:
                            {
                                "$eq":
                                [
                                    {
                                        "$indexOfArray": [ "$comments", "$$this" ]
                                    },
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            then:
                            {
                                "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
                            },
                            else:
                            {
                                "$concat": [ "$$value", ", ", "$$this" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    _id: null,
    comments: 'waiting for pieces, waiting for approval, nothing'
  }
]
```