# distinct strings value and concatenating results giving empty string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

hello im building an app where i distinct the string values of "comments" and "dates"(already strings) and concatenate them in two different strings one for comments and one for reclamation dates I used $addToSet to distinct values but every time the concatenating is giving empty result

this is an example of my work :

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dB3xBFsIfun

ps : i think the problem is in the of using the $addToSet insite $group

Comment: Looks like you are creating duplicate questions for the same use case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276295/distinct-strings-value-and-concatenating-the-results, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267283/ignore-duplicated-string-values-while-concatinating-them-in-mongodb.  What is the difference between these questions.  It is becoming confusing if you keep reposting and don't work through the prior issues with the people who volunteered to help you.  I see your name is SpawN, and you keep spawning similar (if not identical) questions - lol.

Comment: before the group the data are like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9jNx3RDp6RL)  there is no `comment` or `daterec` fields,go stage by stage and see what is happening, i think you need to send sample data and expected output, because its hard people to know what you need.  @barrypicker help spawn, trying but gets no answers. lol

Comment: @barrypicker not the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267283/ignore-duplicated-string-values-while-concatinating-them-in-mongodb i want just to distinct and concatenate but now i couldnt implement that in my new case